# XAMPP error "Apache shutdown unexpectedly."

Tags: apache, xampp

Been having a problem with XAMPP lately. Whenever I try to start up Apache, it starts then stops and displays the following error message:

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Check the "/xampp/apache/logs/error.log" file
and the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
```

When I check the error.log file, the log is mostly filled with the following errors:

```
[Sun Dec 02 23:32:10 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.102] File does not exist: C:/xampp/htdocs/HNAP1
[Sun Dec 02 23:32:10 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.102] no acceptable variant: C:/xampp/apache/error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var
[Sun Dec 02 23:32:13 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.102] File does not exist: C:/xampp/htdocs/TEADevInfo
[Sun Dec 02 23:32:16 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.102] client denied by server configuration: C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/
```

(I'm using XAMPP 1.8.1, with control panel v3.1.0.3.1.0)

This has really had me scratching my head for quite some time now. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Are you using SSL? Have you tried to Fix this error by updating the configuration to force close the SSL service?

If you edit the file `httpd.conf` at `/xampp/Apache/conf` and comment out the line:

```
#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

Try to Start Apache again and see if it worked.

The source of this issue can occasionally be another service listening on port 443.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this and I still got the same error :(